# Upload Generated PDF with AJAX is Not Working or Timing Out

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, jspdf

I am using [JSPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to dynamically generate a PDF with user information on my web app, which is built in React.js and hosted on Firebase.

On the final page, I would like to email this PDF to a list of addresses that the user specifies. This sounds straightforward, but I have encountered some issues. Firstly, I cannot send an email using just React.js. Doing some research has led me to create a request to a PHP file that uploads the file. In the PHP file, I then use the standard PHP mailer to send the emails.

JSPDF has these functions used to export the file:

```
var pdfInBase64 = doc.output('datauristring');
var pdfInRawFormat = doc.output();
```

Here are 2 of my attempts to solve this issue. Both use `FormData`.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("data",  pdfInBase64); // also tried pdfInRawFormat
```

**Using XMLHttpRequest:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'uploader.php', true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      // File(s) uploaded.
      console.log('completed');
    } else {
      alert('An error occurred!');
    }
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

**Using AJAX:**

```
var $ = require ('jquery');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'uploader.php',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Both of the above methods don't seem to be working for me. When I go to my console and look at the "Networking" tab, I see that a request has been made, but it times out after 20+ seconds. I tried not uploading a file and just setting `data` as `hello` or any other string, and the PHP file successfully receives it. I'm thinking that the file that I have is too large, leading to a timeout.

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to fix this? My end goal is to send an email with an attachment using JavaScript and PHP. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution for this?